# How do I include post install scripts in an angular library?

Tags: npm, ng-packagr

I am building an angular library and have figured out how to get assets into the dist folder I'm using it to include a file called "postInstall.js", however I need to run the postInstall.js file, I can do that by including an NPM post install script. However when I run ng build  --prod the script in my package.json is not included inside the package.json in the dist folder. Here is my package.json:

```
{
"name": "mm-api",
"version": "0.0.6",
"scripts": {
    "postinstall": "node postInstall.js"
},
"peerDependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "^10.1.6",
    "@angular/core": "^10.1.6",
    "@angular/material": "^10.2.7"
},
"dependencies": {
    "inputmask": "^5.0.5",
    "sweetalert2": "^10.15.5",
    "tslib": "^2.0.0",
    "work-token": "^1.0.2"
},
"browser": {
    "crypto": false
}
}
```

here is the package.json in the dist folder:

```
    {
  "name": "mm-api",
  "version": "0.0.6",
  "peerDependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "^10.1.6",
    "@angular/core": "^10.1.6",
    "@angular/material": "^10.2.7"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "inputmask": "^5.0.5",
    "sweetalert2": "^10.15.5",
    "tslib": "^2.0.0",
    "work-token": "^1.0.2"
  },
  "browser": {
    "crypto": false
  },
  "main": "bundles/mm-api.umd.js",
  "module": "fesm2015/mm-api.js",
  "es2015": "fesm2015/mm-api.js",
  "esm2015": "esm2015/mm-api.js",
  "fesm2015": "fesm2015/mm-api.js",
  "typings": "mm-api.d.ts",
  "metadata": "mm-api.metadata.json",
  "sideEffects": false
}
```

How do I get angular to include the post install script in the output package.json?

Ps: I know I could just add the post install script in the package.json in the dist folder after build however it seems like that is something someone could easily forget making the library useless for that particular build.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is in the ng-package.json

```
{
"$schema": "../../node_modules/ng-packagr/ng-package.schema.json",
"dest": "../../dist/mm-api",
"assets": ["./postInstall.js"],
"keepLifecycleScripts": true, <----- Needs to be set to true
"whitelistedNonPeerDependencies": [
    "@angular/material",
    "work-token",
    "inputmask",
    "sweetalert2"
],
"lib": {
    "entryFile": "src/projects.ts",
    "styleIncludePaths": ["../mm-api/src/lib/themes"],
    "umdModuleIds": {
        "querystring": "querystring",
        "work-token/async": "work-token/async"
    }
  }
}
```